# Applying css margin to content before images

Tags: html, css

I have text content and images mixed and want to apply css margin to elements directly before and after images (

, ,  can come before or after the image, but I have no control on which one and where)

I am using the following code to apply margin to the elements before the image

```
#single-pg * + img { margin-top: 75px; }
```

Problem is that it adds the margin-top to other images aswell (I want it to apply to all elements EXCEPT images) and I want to add similar to affect content elements after the image

```
#single-pg img + * { margin-bottom: 75px; }
```

html (Wordpress)

```
<div id="single-pg" >
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

so the outcome could be (but could also be in any other order based on the author)

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<image></image>
<image<</image>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<image<</image>
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML?

Comment: You can only target siblings that come after an element, or children of an element in CSS. You can't traverse back up the dom. You could do this with javascript/jquery though. Is that an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear from your description of the issue (and it's hard without seeing your markup); however, if you want `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to apply to every element except for images, I'd make use of the `:not` selector.

```
:not(img) {
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}
```

### EDIT

To target the paragraphs in a more nuanced way, we'll have to use some scripting. We can use the adjacent sibling selector to add our `margin-top` value:

```
img + p {
  margin-top:75px;
}
```

and then we can use the jQuery `.prev()` method to target the paragraph immediately preceding each image:

```
$("img").prev().css("margin-bottom", "75px");
```

[Here is an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1rz5r8c/) of an example in action. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Close, But as I mentioned I want them to apply to elements DIRECTLY before or after an image. So if two paragraphs follow an image, the padding only applies to the one that came right after the image, and not the second one

Comment: Unfortunately, browsers read the DOM like a flow, from top to bottom. There's no way to go back up the DOM and select. You could do it with JavaScript, though, but I don't know if that's allowed in your project. Is it?

Comment: Javascript is allowed, not sure how'd I would accomplish it. Since I am just dealing with margins, I was going to use #single-pg img + * , to target the what I want, but it doesn't work the same as #single-pg * + img

Comment: You'd use the adjacent sibling selector to add `margin-top` and you'd use the jQuery `.prev()` method to target the `<p>` tag before each image. See my edit for an example in action.

Answer (score 0):

Put your images and text in a wrapper and each image and text in another wrapper and you can manage your margin for each image.

Comment: wrappers will help you put any css on anything you want.

Comment: I would have tried that, but then I would have to be able to hard code the elements, but as I mentioned I have no control over their use or location